# Number of ways in which $8$ distinct apples can be distributed among $3$ boys?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Number of ways in which $8$ distinguishable apples can be distributed among $3$ boys such that every boy should get **at least** $1$ apple and **at most** $4$ apples is $K× _7P_3$ then what is the value of $K$..where $K$ is a positive integer?

**my attempt**- I tried solving this by brute force and so I wrote down all the possibilities which satisfy the above condition ....(total $12$(see edit) of them where $B_1,B_2,B_3$ are the three boys)
[image]
But I don't think this is a good solution at all!!.... There are $12$ cases after all also.. we need to solve for each and add them..which is a troubling task indeed...!!!...so can anyone help me in solving this in a much better/shorter way??...or even improve my method..??
..and direct what should I do??

**Edit** : as pointed out in one of the comments...I have indeed missed out the case $3,3,2$..really sorry....this means there are 12 cases....

Comment: Last line sums up to $7$.

Comment: My first instinct would have been to approach via inclusion-exclusion, but it will require just as many calculations as your brute-force approach would require (as there are six conditions that could be violated).  Note, you are missing a case: $(3,3,2)$.  The number of cases in each line would be $\frac{8!}{a!b!c!}$ where $a,b,c$ are the amount of apples received for each boy respectively.  All in all, this is a rather tedious problem in my opinion.

Comment: @Rory daulton for reasons I am unaware of...I am unable to even view your answer...can you please tell me why is it so..???..or is it some problem with my browser setting...

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized it was wrong. I am working on another method.

Comment: I have accepted Rory daultons answer...but...other answers are equally good...and its just a matter of choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out the case "$3$ $3$ $2$" in your list above [before your correction], so that would make $12$ cases. However, I have a better solution that groups your cases together into only $3$ basic cases:

(a) One boy (we'll call him First) gets $4$ applies, another (Second) gets $3$ apples, and the Third gets $1$ apple. We can count this case by first choosing the boys into the order First-Second-Third (3! ways), then choosing the $4$ apples for First ($_8C_4$ ways), then choosing $3$ apples for Second from the remaining $4$ apples ($_4C_3$ ways). The apple for Third is now determined. We end up with the count for this case

$$3! \ \cdot\ _8C_4 \ \cdot\ _4C_3=6 \cdot 70 \cdot 4 = 1680$$

(b) First gets $4$ apples, Second gets $2$ apples, and Third also gets $2$ apples. We can count this case by first choosing the boys into the order First-Others (3 ways): the others get the same number of apples so we don't distinguish them here. Then choose the $4$ apples for First ($_8C_4$ ways), then choosing $2$ apples for one of the other boys from the remaining $4$ apples ($_4C_2$ ways). The apples for the remaining boy are now determined. We end up with the count for this case

$$3 \ \cdot\ _8C_4 \ \cdot\ _4C_2=3 \cdot 70 \cdot 6 = 1260$$

(c) First gets $2$ apples, Second gets $3$ apples, and Third also gets $3$ apples. We can count this case by first choosing the boys into the order First-Others (3 ways): the others get the same number of apples so we don't distinguish them here. Then choose the $2$ apples for First ($_8C_2$ ways), then choosing $3$ apples for one of the other boys from the remaining $6$ apples ($_6C_3$ ways). The apples for the remaining boy are now determined. We end up with the count for this case

$$3 \ \cdot\ _8C_2 \ \cdot\ _6C_3 = 3\cdot 28 \cdot 20 = 1680$$

Thus the total number of possibilities is

$$1680+1260+1680 = 4620$$

We now divide that by $_7P_3$ and get our final answer

> $$22$$

---

I just checked this answer in Microsoft Excel. If you ignore the restrictions on the numbers of apples to each boy there are only $3^8=6561$ ways to distribute the $8$ distinguishable apples among $3$ distinguishable boys. The spreadsheet loops through those and checks which ones meet the additional requirements. Let me know if you need the details.

Comment: You said I quote.. **I have a better solution that groups your cases together into only $3$ ,basic cases**:....well..is there any method/process of finding out those $3$ **basic cases** other than writing all the possibilities (which I Did)..and then finding out the pattern....to make/group them in $3$ cases...

Comment: As I am quite sure that finding the **three cases** without looking at the possibilities (written by me in the question)....would have been indeed quite a difficult task...that is I want to ask.....is there any **method / process** of determining The basic patterns you mentoined other than ..writing all the possibilities (which I have done)..and then seeing the pattern..??

Comment: As I remember your answer to this question...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546160/finding-the-values-for-satisfying-the-given-equality-xyz-7/1546244#1546244

Comment: But here there are other cases also.... Which I am not able to solve by using equations...like you did...in the question I talked about in previous comment...

Comment: @Freelancer: I did not find my $3$ cases by looking at your cases: I did the opposite, by finding my cases *then* comparing them to yours, and saw that you should have had $12$ cases. (A mistake in my work, exercise, and my computer acting up delayed my final answer, but I saw the cases long before you made your correction or got any other answers.) I have some experience with permutations and combinations, in both math problems and computer programs, so I was able to just be systematic and find all the possibilities.

Comment: @Freelancer: I just looked at all possibilities in reverse lexigraphical order. First may have $4$ apples. If Second gets $4$ then Third gets none: not allowed. So $4 3 1$ is the first possibility. Continue in lexigraphical order: then we get $4 2 2$. Reducing Second further destroys the lexigraphical order, so now reduce First to $3$, and Second can have at most $3$, so we get $3 3 2$. We can't reduce Second further and keep lexigraphical order, but we can't reduce First either, so we are done and have found all possibilities. Just be systematic!

Answer (score 4):

There are only $3$ basic *patterns:* $4-3-1,\;$ $4-2-2,\;$ and $3-3-2$

Ways of distributing distinct objects to distinct boxes in these patterns is given by the multinomial coefficients,$\dbinom{8}{4,3,1},\dbinom{8}{4,2,2},\dbinom{8}{3,3,2}$

However, since the persons are distinct, we also need to consider the permutations of the patterns which would be $6,3\;$ and $3$ respectively for the $3$ patterns

Thus $K = \dfrac{6\dbinom{8}{4,3,1}+3\dbinom{8}{4,2,2}+3\dbinom{8}{3,3,2}}{_7P_3} = 22$

Comment: There's something I'm confused about in this answer. So, for example, for the pattern $4-3-1$, there are $6$ ways of ordering it (and ordering is important because the boys are distinguishable--that is $x^4$$y^3$$z$, $x^4$$y$$z^3$, $x^3$$y^4$$z$, $x^3$$y$$z^4$, $x$$y^4$$z^3$, $x$$y^3$$z^4$ are all different).   Thus, the first term in the expression for $K$ should be multiplied by $6$. Similarly, the succeeding two terms should each be multiplied by 3 because there are $3$ ways of ordering $4-2-2$ and $3-3-2$.  With these changes, the expression for $K$ gives 22.

Comment: You are quite right. I overlooked this point, and have amended the answer. Thanks for the good "catch" ! +1

Comment: @true blue anil... is there any method / process of determining The **basic patterns** you mentoined other than ..writing all the possibilities (which I have done)..and then seeing the pattern..??

Comment: And sorry...but I don't know/use much multinomial theorem ...so for example does this..$$\dbinom{8}{4,3,1}$$ in your answer mean this...??$$_8C_4×_4C_3×_1C_1$$

Comment: Yes, it is a convenient way of condensing your longer expression.

Comment: The **basic patterns** do not contain permutations, so less error prone. You just list them systematically, my preference is to go down from the largest "number" (431) and move down.

Answer (score 2):

I think for this particular question, it is easy to count the required number of ways in the following way:

See that there are only the following distributions of the apples among the three boys are to be ignored: $(1, 2, 5), (1, 5, 2), (2, 1, 5)(2, 5, 1)(5, 1, 2)(5, 2, 1), (1, 1, 6), (1, 6, 1), (6, 1, 1)$

Now see that for each permutation of the combination $(1, 2, 5)$, There are $^8C_5*^3C_2*^1C_1$  ways and hence for distributions corresponding to the **six permutations** of $(1, 2, 5)$, the total number of ways of distributing the distinguishable apples is $6*^8C_5*^3C_2*^1C_1$

Similarly, for each of the three permutations of the combination $(1, 1, 6)$, there are $^8C_6*^2C_1*^1C_1$ ways of distributing the apples and hence for the combination $(1, 1, 6)$ the total number of ways of distributing the apples are $3*^8C_6*^2C_1*^1C_1$

And finally since the total number of ways of distributing the eight apples among three boys so that each boy gets at least one apple is $3^8 - 3(2^8 - 2) - 2$, $\mathbb{the \ total \ number \ of \ correct \ ways \ of \ distributing \ the \ apples} = \left [ 3^8 - 3(2^8-2) - 3(1^8) \right ] - 3 \ ^8C_6 \ ^2C_1 \ ^1C_1 - 6 \ ^8C_5 \ ^3C_2 \ ^1C_1 = 4620$

Therefore, $K = {4620\over ^7P_3} = {4620\over 210} = 22$
P.S.: You can find th number of ways of distributing the apples among the three boys so that each boy gets at least one apple, by finding the number of ways in which at least one boy doesn't get any apple, i.e. the number of ways in which two boys don't get any apple ($= 3$, i.e. choosing one boy out of the three boys who gets all 8 apples ) and the number of ways in which only one boy doesn't get any apple ( $= 3(2^8 - 2)$, i.e. choosing one boy out of three who doesn't get any apple and then distributing the eight apples among the remaining two boys in such a way that each boy gets at least one apple). Since the total number of ways of distributing the apples among the three boys is $3^8$, the number of ways of distributing so that each boy gets at least one apple is $3^8 - 3( 2^8 - 2 ) - 3$.

Comment: They are $5$ distinct apples

Comment: Among other things, doesn't your analysis implicitly assume that the $8$ apples are INDISTINGUISHABLE and the problem specifically states that they are DISTINGUISHABLE?  Moreover, you didn't really solve for K, did you?  And your answer certainly wouldn't lead to integer K.

Comment: You have written and I quote .. **And finally since the total number of ways of distributing the eight apples among three boys so that each boy gets at least one apple is $3^8$** ...so this means you are saying for each of the apple($8$ in total)..there are 3 options/3 boys ...but in this there is  a possibility of one boy getting all the apples (in 3 cases)...but you have written ..distributing the eight apples among **three boys** so that each boy **gets at least one apple is $3^8$**

Comment: Also things have become  a little bit shabby in the last two lines can you please explain them s little bit more...